# Bad chart when building using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the code I have written to regenerate a chart each time a button is pressed:

```
Sub MakeChart()
    ActiveWorkbook.Charts("cht_hgn_hgn").Delete
    Dim s As Series
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cs As Chart
    Set sh = Worksheets("clc_hgn_hgn")
    Set cs = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
    cs.Name = "cht_hgn_hgn"
    cs.ChartType = xlLine
    For iCount = 3 To 3
        Debug.Print (iCount)
        Set s = cs.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        s.Name = sh.Cells(1, iCount).Value
        s.values = sh.Range(sh.Cells(3, iCount), sh.Cells(41, iCount))
        s.XValues = sh.Range(sh.Cells(3, 1), sh.Cells(41, 1))
    Next iCount
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of the source data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrZHi.jpg[image]

Here is a screenshot of the chart:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfFno.jpg[image]

The problem is that the labels (at the very least) in the legend and along the x axis appear to be really messed up. What have I done wrong in my code?

Thanks!!

Comment: If you can fix the chart manually, then Record Macro and check the generated code. The problem is with the empty cells in your source ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two issues with your data and creating a chart from it.

First: You need setting the way that blank cells are plotted on the chart. For this [Chart.DisplayBlanksAs Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838172.aspx) can be used.

Second: While `ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add` "default" series where added from the data of the active worksheet. Those series you probably not need an therefore should be deleted.

So probably:

```
Sub MakeChart()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Charts("cht_hgn_hgn").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim s As Series
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cs As Chart
    Dim lLastRow As Long, lColumnCount As Long, lLastColumn As Long

    Set sh = Worksheets("clc_hgn_hgn")
    lLastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lLastColumn = 5

    Set cs = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
    cs.Name = "cht_hgn_hgn"
    cs.ChartType = xlLine

    'set the way that blank cells are plotted on the chart
    cs.DisplayBlanksAs = xlInterpolated
    'delete the series which are created while ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
    'since we want creating our own series now
    For Each s In cs.SeriesCollection
     s.Delete
    Next

    For lColumnCount = 3 To lLastColumn
        Debug.Print (lColumnCount)
        Set s = cs.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        s.Name = sh.Cells(1, lColumnCount).Value
        s.Values = sh.Range(sh.Cells(3, lColumnCount), sh.Cells(lLastRow, lColumnCount))
        s.XValues = sh.Range(sh.Cells(3, 1), sh.Cells(lLastRow, 1))
    Next lColumnCount

End Sub
```

Comment: Good answer. I did not use xlInterpolated however. If zero values are a problem, then maybe I am using the wrong chart type.